# TSLint returns expected an assignment or function call

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I am checking my angular project with tslint, and I am getting this error from which I don't understand the reason. The error is: expected an assignment or function call

```
getInfoPrinting() {
this.imprimirService.getInfoPrinting().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.printingOrders = response.data;
    this.totalNumberOfCharacters = 0;
    this.totalNumberOfCharactersNext = 0;
    if (this.printingOrders.labelPresentOrder && this.printingOrders.labelPresentOrder.lines) {
      this.printingOrders.labelPresentOrder.lines.forEach(
        line => {
          this.totalNumberOfCharacters += line.length;
        }
      );
    }
    if (this.printingOrders.labelNextOrder && this.printingOrders.labelNextOrder.lines) {
      this.printingOrders.labelNextOrder.lines.forEach(
        line => {
          this.totalNumberOfCharactersNext += line.length;
        }
      );
    }
    if (this.printingOrders.printing) {
      this.suscribeNotifications();
    }
  }
), err => {
  this.loading = false;
  this.alertService.error(INFO_NO_EXISTEN_ORDEN_PREPARADA);
  this.hasAlert = true;
};
```

}

The error is in this line:

```
this.imprimirService.getInfoPrinting().subscribe(
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's your linter here, I think your closing parenthesis and the comma separating the callback arguments to ```subcribe``` are misplaced.

Comment: Try putting `response` inside parenthesis, like this: `this.imprimirService.getInfoPrinting().subscribe((response) => { ... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. Instead of

```
getInfoPrinting() {
    this.imprimirService.getInfoPrinting().subscribe(
      response => {
        ...
      }
    ), err => {
      ...
    };
}
```

It should be

```
getInfoPrinting() {
    this.imprimirService.getInfoPrinting().subscribe(
      response => {
        ...
      }, 
      err => {
      ...
    });
}
```

The error would be much easier to spot if the method body was shorter. You should delegate to a separate method inside your callback.

Comment: What's the difference between putting the response in parenthesis or without them? Example: `.subscribe((response) => { ... })`

Comment: None. Parentheses are needed if you have several arguments (or none).